# Excel: Formulas and dropdown lists

Tags: excel, validation

I am trying to make a cell display the result of a VLOOKUP but allow the user to change the cells value to something from a dropdown list if they choose to.

I don't want the formula to be visible to the user.

The problem I'm having is when the user picks a different value from the list the formula is erased. When the criteria for the formula changes I want it to update to the new result.

I'm using Excel 2010. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You would need to place the VLOOKUP in a different cell and reference the drop down list in the VLOOKUP. If you can post a picture or example of your data, that would be helpful.

Comment: This sounds like it would require a [tag:VBA] solution

Answer (score 0):

We can use an extra cell or two.  In **A3** we put a number and in **A2** we can enter from a drop-down list.  In **A1** we have:

```
=IF(A2<>"",A2,VLOOKUP(A3,C1:D13,2,FALSE))
```

So if **A2** is blank, we use the *VLOOKUP()*.  If **A2** has a value, we use that value.

[image]